# When an instance variable has the same name as the class

Tags: java, java-8

Could somebody please explain the meaning of this in Java

```
 public class Test{
     // instance variables go here...

     protected static Test mtest;

     // methods go here
 }
```

I am trying to grasp what the field mtest represents. I know that in Java to create an instance of an object I have to use to the new keyword, however that isn't being used here.

Within the same class I can do actions such as this:

```
   mtest.someMethod();
```

This leads me to believe that this is similar to the use of the this pointer in C++, such as

```
   this->aMemberFunction();
```

Could somebody please explain what protected static Test mtest means?

This is not a duplicate of the question: "Why should one avoid using protected static in Java"

Comment: @ghosh I think the OP is asking about why there is no `new` keyword here. He/she comes to the wrong conclusion that this has something to do with `protected static`.

Comment: Some bad implementations of lazy singleton pattern would have declaration like this. Is your code implementing singleton here?

Comment: @tsolakp I'll agree, this very much looks like a singleton pattern here

Answer (score 1):

It is, as you said, similar to a pointer in C++. However, since you did not initialise it, calling methods or accessing fields of it will cause a `NullPointerException` to be thrown.

The compiler lets you write `mtest.someMethod();` because the compiler trusts you that you would eventually initialise `mtest` when the program is running. If you don't, as I said just now, you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

To avoid this `NullPointerException`, you need to create a new object and assign it to `mtest`, using the `new` keyword:

```
mtest = new Test();
```

Comment: *calling methods or accessing fields of it will cause a NullPointerException to be thrown*, unless those fields or methods are static

Answer (score 0):

As you already guessed this is a reference on an instance of the defining `class Test`. A typical use case is with singleton pattern where you have one and only one instance of the class and protects against creation of additional instances by a private constructor.

```
public class Test {
    private static final Test mtest = new Test();
    private Test() { ... }
    public static void method() { /* do something using mtest */ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you declare a class you able to use type of this class inside of it.
 Or in another word you able to assign any Test or it's child instances ([IS-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) rule, any class that extends Test) to `mtest` field:

```
 public class Test{

     //default constructor already present when we don't specify our own 
     protected static Test mtest = new Test();

 }
```

When you don't assign anything to this field it will be null

```
public class Test{

     protected static Test mtest; // null

 }
```

So in since we resolved question about type of the field let's talk about static and protected modifiers.
Static means that field initialized right after class loaded by jvm, because static
field belongs to class itself and we able to use it with name of the class i.e. `Test.mtest`
When we define static method same rule is here, we use it in the same way `Test.doSomething()`
    In other words class is like *special kind of object* we able to invoke methods or assign a field of it but
also able to use it like blueprint to create instances. (something like prototypes in js)
    But we don't able to use instance methods from static contents because from static point of view
no one instance is created and we have only class because in instance methods presented `this`. It's passed to every instance methods but it hidden from developer and in static `this` is not present.
protected means that you want to class from different package that extends Test is able to access to `mtest` field
but no one class outside from Test package don't able to see mtest field.

**Static and not static context.**

When we remove all syntax sugar and trying to understand 
static and not static context in low level it's will be like that (that called prototype based oop, it's how js, lua etc. languages dealing with oop)

For modelling classes and instances we need only one structure that behaves like Map (key - value pairs) and functions:

Let's define type (object) cat, we need to produce many of them
since we want to have many cats we need place where to store 
unique characteristics
and this place will be separate object {}

```
Cat = {
    new = (this, name) -> {         
        newCat = {};                //create empty object {}
        newCat.name = name;         //assign to key name of this object value name
        setPrototype(newCat, this)  // assign where is newCat will search for keys (Cat object)  
                                    //when it's no able to find it in ourself 
        return newCat;              // return newly created cat
    }

// THIS passed to method, it's method like instance method in java but in java THIS is hidden
    printName = (this) -> {         
        print ("hello " .. this.name)
    },

// no THIS keyword here, same as static methods in java
    averageCatLifeInYears = () -> { 
        print(10);
    }


};
```

**INSTANCE**

how it works:
we have Cat object that behaves like map in java, invoke value (function) for key `new`
and for create new instances we need to pass object in which newly created instance
will search methods when new instance don't find them in itself

```
fooCat = Cat.new(Cat, "foo");  
barCat = Cat.new(Cat, "bar");
```

First, in object fooCat we trying to find function by key `printName` and execute it.
Why we need to pass foocat to foocat `printName` function? it's bacause only one place where 
name "foo" is present is fooCat object! 
Second step when fooCat doesn't find that key (printName) in key value pairs fooCat see to it's prototype 
(that behaviour we assigned in constructor earlier by language `setPrototype()` special function)
fooCat finds function in Cat and pass to it reference to itself.
In that function from passed reference function trying to get string value by key `name` and pass it to a print method.
In fooCat object by key `name` stored value "foo" and "foo" will be printed.

```
 fooCat.printName(fooCat);
```

**STATIC**

Trying to execute averageCatLifeInYears() method from fooCat instance
we don't need to pass fooCat to function
like in previous example, or even more we able to invoke it from Cat class
itself without any Cat class instances!

```
Cat.averageCatLifeInYears() // no value passed to method
```

Or, fooCat trying to find method by name and find it in Cat class since
that method STATIC we don't need any instance
passed to it from which we retrieve unique info like in previous example:

```
 fooCat.averageCatLifeInYears(); // no value passed, this method is static
```

After we emerged this language to world many developers starts to complain
 about language verbosity and we decide to add some syntax sugar and hide
 that dumb pass itself to every function as first argument.
We introduce brand new :: operator with help of we passed object from which we call method 
as first parameter to that method. 
In this way we hide THIS behind the scene but it's remains on its place, even if we can not see it.

```
fooCat = Cat::new(Cat, "foo");  
fooCat = Cat::new(/*this hides here*/ "foo");
```

Since we hide verbosity that methods looks like the same now but THIS present in printnName() method
this two methods have different context and in java averageCatLifeInYears() will be marked STATIC

```
fooCat::printName(); 
Cat::averageCatLifeInYears();
```

So why in java we don't able to use instance context from static?
 try to rewrite our Cat class to model this in java

```
Cat = {
    new = (this, name) -> {         
        newCat = {};                
        newCat.name = name;         
        setPrototype(newCat, this)  
        return newCat;              
    },


    printName = (this) -> {  // need instance where is placed name to work
        print ("hello " .. this.name)
    },

    //tryint to invoke instance context from static
    averageCatLifeInYears = () -> { 
        print(10);
        //lets try to invoke printName from this method...
        printName(?????) // WHAT WE NEED TO PLACE HERE???
    }
};
```

Since we able to invoke `averageCatLifeInYears()` from Cat without any argument
            and trying to invoke method that needs argument (THIS) from wich we get name
            we get error in runtime or COMPILE error in more intellegent languages like java.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you offer further explanation of what this means:  But we don't able to use instance methods from static contents because from static point of view no one instance is created and we have only class because in instance methods presented this. It's passed to every instance methods but it hidden from developer and in static this is not present. protected means that you want to class from different package that extends Test is able to access to mtest field but no one class outside from Test package don't able to see mtest field. Once again, thank you.

Comment: @StrayPointer what exactly do you not understand?

Comment: What do you mean by: we have only class because in instance methods presented this.   Also what is passed to every instance method? This sentence is confusing:  It's passed to every instance methods but it hidden from developer and in static this is not present

Comment: @StrayPointer I added more verbose explanation, hope it's help